# Counterexample For Subspaces of Normed Linear Spaces

Tags: real-analysis, functional-analysis, analysis

An exercise in Folland's analysis book is to show that given any normed vector space $X$ and proper closed subspace $M$, for $\epsilon > 0$ there exists a point $x\in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$ and $\inf\{\|x - m \| : m\in M\} \ge 1-\epsilon$.

In a Hilbert space, we can find an $x\in X$ with $\|x\| = 1$ and $\inf\{\|x - m \| : m\in M\} = 1$.  What is an example where such an $x$ cannot be found?  Also, is there necessarily such an $x$ in a Banach space?